# CORS redirect from http to https

Tags: nginx, redirect, cors

Just found out that when you return 301 Redirect status from your server to a CORS request, **the browser set the subsequent 'Origin' header to 'null'**. Apparently this is for privacy reason, but I'm only referring from http to https in my nginx server! Oh well.. what can you do.

On my nginx config for https, I am checking $http_origin before adding my CORS headers. Since the browser set the damn Origin header to 'null', the header didn't got added to the response.

Is there anyway around this problem or I'm forced to just make sure my Origin client sends only https requests?

Hope the question is not too broad.

Comment: I think you might be able to avoid the redirect by sending a 'Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests' response header with the document your frontend code is in. That response header tells the browser: for any URLs from that document which are http URLs, replace those with https URLs before actually making the requests for them. Try it. If that works, it should prevent your code in that document from ever running into the redirect case you’re hitting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol scheme is one of the elements that define Origin, so `http://x.com` is a different origin from `https://x.com`

In CORS, after redirect, the browser sends `Origin: null`, this is by design.

To overcome this you have two options:

1. Allow `Origin: null` but please make sure you understand the implications as it actually means you're allowing all origins.
2. Add to the redirect url some proof that this is a valid url that came from your server. Some secret that only the server can generate. When Origin: null is present, allow it only if this is a valid secret.

Comment: Hmm.. Does that mean it won't be safe to have one secret key since everyone can just view it on redirect response and I'll have to deal with some kind of public key cryptography to be secure?

Comment: Yes, this should be short lived key which includes some client identifiers such as client ip. You don't have to use public/private key, simple symmetric key would suffice.